# Вызов метода это выражение или оператор?

Tags: c#, терминология, выражение

Если я вызову метод Console.WriteLine("Hello!"); он будет оператором или выражением, или выражением он будет считаться тогда,когда метод будет возвращать некоторое значение?

Comment: Оператор это statement?

Comment: @dIm0n да,но не уверен,что употребляю этот термин правильно

Comment: [Expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions), [Statements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открываем [спецификацию](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm):

> 12.7.6 Invocation expressions
>
> 12.7.6.1 General
>
> An invocation-expression is used to invoke a method.
>
> invocation-expression:
>     primary-expression   (   argument-list <sub>opt</sub>   )

То есть вызов метода - это выражение. Вызов метода является выражением, даже если тип возвращаемого значения void, об этом сказано далее в том же пункте:

> The result of evaluating an invocation-expression is classified as follows:
>
> • If the invocation-expression invokes a method or delegate that returns void, the result is nothing. An expression that is classified as nothing is permitted only in the context of a statement-expression (§13.7) or as the body of a lambda-expression (§12.16). Otherwise a binding-time error occurs.
>
> • Otherwise, the result is a value, with an associated type of the return type of the method or delegate